# Pandas create quantile bins of column based on count from another column

Tags: python, pandas, quantile

I have a pandas dataframe like:

```
domain       | conv_value | n_convs
etsy.com     | 100.00     | 20
etsy.com     | 50.00      | 100
etsy.com     | 25.00      | 450
allbirds.com | 80.00      | 1000
allbirds.com | 160.00     | 5
...
```

I want to create quantile bins for conv_value based on the number of conversions (n_convs). I can use `pd.qcut(df.conv_value, q=4)` to create the bins based only on conv_value, but this doesn't take into account the actual n_convs. I am wondering if anyone knows a solution other than "exploding out" n_convs making etsy.com conv_value = 100.00 repeat 20 times.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid "exploding out" your dataframe, you can sort your DataFrame by `conv_values` first and then create a cumulative column for `n_convs`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"conv_value": [100, 50, 25, 80, 160], "n_convs": [20,100,450,1000,5]})
df.sort_values(by="conv_value", inplace=True, ignore_index=True)
df["n_cum"] = df["n_convs"].cumsum()
```

Your DataFrame will look something like this:

```
conv_value | n_convs | n_cum
-----------|---------|-------
25         | 450     | 450
50         | 100     | 550
80         | 1000    | 1550
100        | 20      | 1570
160        | 5       | 1575
```

Now you can create your quartile bins based on the cumulative column.